# Return a python DataFrame with full rows containing the highest sales for each company

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have the following data table:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Company':['ELCO','ELCO','ELCO','BOBCO','BOBCO','BOBCO','LAMECO','LAMECO','LAMECO'],
       'Person':['Sam','Mikey','Amy','Vanessa','Carl','Sarah','Emily','Laura','Steve'],
       'Sales':[220,123,312,125,263,321,243,275,198]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

How would I go about logically extracting the data to end up with a data table that just shows the highest 'Sales' for each company whist keeping the full rows for those highest sales figures. In other words, how would I get the smaller DataFrame shown at the bottom of the attached image using conditional logic etc?

DataFrame Outputs

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `groupby().idxmax()` and `loc`:

```
df.loc[df.groupby('Company').Sales.idxmax()]
```

Output:

```
  Company Person  Sales
5   BOBCO  Sarah    321
2    ELCO    Amy    312
7  LAMECO  Laura    275
```

**Note**: The above gives you only **one** sale person per company. If you want **all** sale persons with max sale in each company, you need `transform`:

```
 df[df['Sales'] == df.groupby('Company').Sales.transform('max')]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was after. Thank you!